# Create a redundant folder

Tags: windows-10, security, redundancy

The operating system I am using is Windows 10 Enterprise. I had a folder on a shared drive of my employers network with data that was deleted by someone. I don't know who or why. I have found some things online about changing permissions of who can access the folder, but the options for permissions are really convoluted and I'm not sure which selections will prevent or allow the people who I want to have access to the folder will give them permission or not.

So, what I would like to know if there is a way to create a redundant folder that will automatically update with any information that I put in the source folder? Please let me be clear here. A Shortcut will not meet my needs. I need the information to remain in the redundant folder if the source folder is deleted.

Also, I don't want any help with the permissions issue. It would be far more valuable to me to just have the solution of a redundant folder.

Comment: It sounds like you may want what Microsoft called 'Briefcase'; there's an explanation and instructions [here](https://www.techmesto.com/how-to-enable-briefcase-feature-in-windows-10/)

Comment: As the file was on a network drive, there should be a backup of it that can be retrieved for you.

Comment: 'deleted by someone' - I'd be asking IT how that was even allowed to happen in the first place.